Genie Builder won't start. I get the following: ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: `BE8` not defined
I have installed genie builder, but I cannot start.
Here is the installation order:
1- I installed Julia language in my computer
2- I then installed genie.jl using  Pkg.add(Genie)
3- I then installed VS code
4- I then installed Julia extension in VS code
5- I then installed Genie Builder from VS code
Steps 1 to 5 went successfully.
I then tried to start Genie Builder but ran  cannot start it.  Here is the error message.
GB Version. Previous: 1.0.27. Current: 1.0.27
PS C:\Users\Caesar Edward.vscode\extensions\geniebuilder.geniebuilder-1.0.27\scripts> $env:GB_PORT='10101'; $env:GB_APP_BASEPATH=''; $env:GB_APP_WSEXPPORT=''; $env:GB_APP_WSBASEPATH=''; $env:HOST='127.0.0.1';  julia --startup-file=no --depwarn=no c:\Users\Caesar Edward.vscode\extensions\geniebuilder.geniebuilder-1.0.27\scripts\rungb.jl
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: BE8 not defined
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope
@ c:\Users\Caesar:1
in expression starting at c:\Users\Caesar:1
PS C:\Users\Caesar Edward.vscode\extensions\geniebuilder.geniebuilder-1.0.27\scripts>
To start Genie Builder
